# How to update react component on parent changes?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How to update react component on parent changes?

Following is a functional component.
It receives the prop `id` from a parent component (which is class based) and (the id is dynamic and changes)..

So based on the `id` I am doing the following rendering.

```
const DataComp = ({ id,  }: any) => {


  return (
    <div className="myComp">
      <div className="data" >
        {MY_ITEMS[id].data.map(({ id, title, body }: any) => (
          <div key={id}>
            <p>{title}</p>
            <p>{body}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default DataComp;
```

But I'm getting the error cannot read  the property map of undefined.

When I do a console log inside the `DataComp` I can see the value of`MY_ITEMS[id].data`.
I assume that for a fraction of second the `MY_ITEMS[id].data` is undefined.

So I  tried the following methods

```
MY_ITEMS[id].data?.map
```

```
(MY_ITEMS[id].data || []).map
```

```
 MY_ITEMS[id].data && MY_ITEMS[id].data.map
```

But none of these is causing the update of the UI.

This is the parent component (which is class based)

```
class Parent extends Component<any, any> {
  constructor() {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentId: MY_ITEMS[0].id,
    };
  }

componentDidMount() {
this.setId(MY_ITEMS[0].id)
}


async setId(id) {
this.setState({currentId: id})

const someOtherAPIData = await getSomeOtherAPIData()

this.setState({someOtherAPIData})
}

  public render() {

    return (
      <div className="parent">
        <DataComp id={this.state.currentId} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Parent;
```

Note `MY_ITEMS` is an object and `MY_ITEMS[id].data` is an array.

Comment: You are likely correct that on an initial render that `id` is undefined, or that `MY_ITEMS[id].data` is undefined. Can you share what the value of `MY_ITEMS` is so we may see what a `data` array may possibly be?

Comment: data is simply an array. Also I have an initial value for the state from the parent. So there is no undefined id> Im not sure why>

Comment: Initial state is `currentId: MY_ITEMS[0].id,`, so is `MY_ITEMS` an object or an array? Is `MY_ITEMS[0].id` then a valid key/index for `MY_ITEMS[id]` in the child component? This really would be easier if you just showed what an example `MY_ITEMS` value is. Without that or a reproducible code example for you, we're not able to independently reproduce the issue to help resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

For any edge cases where `id` is undefined or not a valid key in your `MY_ITEMS` object, you should guard the undefined access/mapping. Use Optional Chaining on the `MY_ITEMS[id]`, i.e. `MY_ITEMS[id]?.data`. This assumes that if `MY_ITEMS[id]` is defined that there is a `data` property array to then map.

```
const DataComp = ({ id }: any) => {
  return (
    <div className="myComp">
      <div className="data" >
        {MY_ITEMS[id]?.data.map(({ id, title, body }: any) => (
          <div key={id}>
            <p>{title}</p>
            <p>{body}</p>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

If there's a chance even the `data` property could be undefined then Optional Chain there as well, i.e. `MY_ITEMS[id]?.data?.map(....`.

Comment: I tried this way ```MY_ITEMS[id]?``` But getting cannot read the property map of undefined.

Comment: When I try ```(MY_ITEMS[id].data || []).map``` or  ``` MY_ITEMS[id].data && MY_ITEMS[id].data.map``` or ```MY_ITEMS[id].data?.map``` the error is gone. But the UI is not getting updated.

Comment: @mx_code What sort of `id` values is your data using (*for the React keys*)? Can you provide example data?

Comment: These are random strings already present inside each data item. Not numbers or indices.

Comment: I am receiving data inside the child component as this is evident when I do a console log. But for no reason cannot read the property map of undefined.

Comment: @mx_code Without an example of the data you are trying to render it is a bit difficult to say why something isn't updating. Including data seems to be part of providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Can you explain what you mean "receiving data inside the child component"? What and where are you logging?

Comment: I mean I am receiving the id from the parent to child component. And using that id I am displaying the data like this ```MY_ITEMS[id].data ``` inside the child.

Comment: Inside the parent component there is a set Id method which is async.

Comment: Please check the parent component inside my question.

Comment: @mx_code Since you are using a class-based component did you bind your variable (id)?

Answer (score 0):

if there is a possibility that before map some object be undifined you can change your code to this to not getting error:

```
 {MY_ITEMS[id] && MY_ITEMS[id].data && MY_ITEMS[id].data.map(({ id, title, body }: any) => ...
```

this way your last part of code not be execute if there is an undefined some where.
but if it never be execute, you must check the object have id key like below:

```
id="x"
{
"x":{...}
}
```